# wpf datagrid single click edit with DataGridTemplateColumn not working

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, data-binding

I'm creating datagrid columns dynamically based on a parsed csv file.  Essentially I'm following the technique [here](http://paulstovell.com/blog/dynamic-datagrid), however I'm using a DataGridTemplateColumn as I need to specify a combo as an editing control.

I also want to have a single click edit, and I'm following the technique suggested in this article [here by Julie Lerman](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983481.aspx) who wrapped her combo in a grid and used the *FocusManager.FocusedElement* to set focus.

I'm doing this in the ViewModel and the code to create the combo element looks like this:

```
private static FrameworkElementFactory CreateComboElement(int columnIndex, List<string> fieldNameMappings)
{
    //note we create the combo in a grid and use the FocusManager to get focus on 1 click!

    //so first the grid
    FrameworkElementFactory gridElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
    Binding gridBinding = new Binding();
    gridBinding.ElementName = "combo";
    gridElement.SetValue(System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.FocusedElementProperty, gridBinding);

    //now the combo
    FrameworkElementFactory cboElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
    gridElement.AppendChild(cboElement);

    //set the ItemsSource on the combo
    Binding comboBinding = new Binding();
    comboBinding.Source = fieldNameMappings;
    cboElement.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, comboBinding);
    cboElement.SetValue(ComboBox.NameProperty, "combo");
    cboElement.SetValue(ComboBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemProperty, false);

    //now set the binding for the selected vlaue in the combo
    Binding selectedBinding = new Binding(string.Format("Properties[{0}].Value", columnIndex));
    cboElement.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, selectedBinding);
    return gridElement;
}
```

The problem is, the one click edit doesn't work and at runtime I see the following error after the 2nd click which is still required to invoke editing:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=combo'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'Grid' (Name=''); target property is 'FocusedElement' (type 'IInputElement')
```

What is wrong, why is the single click not working?

Answer (score 0):

You have to intercept the DataGridCell's OnGotFocus event, set the cell's mode to IsEditing, then intercept the Loaded event for the actor control in your *CellEditingTemplate*:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style
        x:Key="AutoEditModeOnClick"
        TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

        <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="DataGridCell_OnGotFocus" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn
        CellStyle="{StaticResource AutoEditModeOnClick}"
        Header="Score">

        <!-- Example with ComboBox -->

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Some more XAML -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Some more XAML -->
                <ComboBox
                    DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                    SelectedValuePath="RecordID"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Score,
                        TargetNullValue=0,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ScoreOptions,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                            AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                    Loaded="Combobox_Loaded"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn
        CellStyle="{StaticResource AutoEditModeOnClick}"
        Header="Comment">

        <!-- Example with TextBox -->

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Some more XAML -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Some more XAML -->
                <TextBox
                    Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"
                    Text="{Binding Comment,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

In your code-behind, you need three handlers; one for the cell, and one for each type of control (ComboBox, TextBox):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Skips the 'DataGridCell.Focus' step and goes straight into IsEditing
    /// </summary>
    private void DataGridCell_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        cell.IsEditing = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Skips the 'IsEditing' step and goes straight into IsDropDownOpen
    /// </summary>
    private void Combobox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Skips the 'IsEditing' step and goes straight into Focus
    /// </summary>
    private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        textBox.Focus();
    }
```